# Variance of the standard normal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance

> > Suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$. Find $\mathrm{E}(X)$ and $\mathrm {Var} (X)$.

I have found $E(X)=0$. It's easy. While calculating variance of $X$ I got $2$ where as the actual answer should be $1$. Here's how I proceed $:$

$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var} (X) &= \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-{\frac {x^2} 2}}\ dx \\
&= \sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-{\frac {x^2} 2}}\ dx \\
\end{align*}$$ Now taking the substitution $\frac {x^2} 2 = y$ I found that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-{\frac {x^2} 2}}\ dx &= \sqrt {2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} y^{\frac 1 2}\ dy \\
&= \sqrt {2}\ \Gamma \left ({\frac 3 2} \right) \\
&= \sqrt {\frac {\pi} 2} \\
\end{align*}$$

So $$\begin{align*}
\mathrm {Var} (X) &= \sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi}}.\sqrt {\frac {\pi} 2} \\ 
&= 1 \\
\end{align*}$$

Please check my calculation? Thank you very much.

Comment: But you are using the fact that the mean is zero and the variance is 1 in the PDF of the random variable!! Why do you want to calculate them, while they are given?

Comment: No I want to verify it @Blackmath.

Comment: Verify the given? I still don't see the point. You used the measures themselves to calculate them. When you write the PDF as $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$ you assume that the mean is zero and the variance is 1. But then you go ahead to find them!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $\Gamma(3/2)$, not $\Gamma(1/2)$.  Note that $$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-y} y^{t-1}\; dy$$

EDIT: Now it's right.

Comment: if I take that substitution at the very first stage I could get $\frac 1 2$ instead of $1$. What's the problem then @Robert Israel?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^2/2$ is not one-to-one on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E(X^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx$$
Use integration by parts 
\begin{equation}
 \int fg' = fg - \int f'g
\end{equation}
By taking $f = x$ and $g' = xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$
we get $f' = 1$ and $g = -e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx
=-x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-{\displaystyle\int}-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Use $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx
=-x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2s}}
\underbrace{{}
{}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}\,\mathrm{d}u}_{\operatorname{erf}(u)}
\end{equation}
Using $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ we get
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx
=\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} 
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 E(X^2)
 =
 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Big(\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\Big)
 =
 \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
 +
 \Gamma(x)
 \Big\vert_0^{\infty}
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma(x) =  K x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ goes to zero at $x = 0$ and $+\infty$. So
\begin{equation}
 E(X^2) = \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Big\vert_0^{\infty} = 1 - 0 =1
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
 Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 = 1 - 0 = 1
\end{equation}